# (airflow) emr steps operator -> emr steps sensor; sensor failed -> trigger before operator

Tags: airflow

I want to handle failovers.
But, sensor failed -> retries only sensor self.

But, I want to trigger before operator.

This is flow chart.

```
a -> a_sensor (failed) -> a (retry) -> a_sensor -> (done)
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend waiting the EMR job in the operator itself, even if this keeps the task running and occupying the worker slot, but it doesn't consume much resources, and you can simply manage the timeout, cleanup and the retry strategy:

```py
class EmrOperator(BaseOperator):
    ...
    def execute():
        run_job():
        wait_job()

    def wait_job():
        while not (is_finished()):
            sleep(10s)
    def on_kill():
        cleanup()
```

And you can use the official operator [EmrAddStepsOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr.EmrAddStepsOperator) which already supports [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr.py#L80-L80).

And if you want to implement what you have mentioned in the question, Airflow doesn't support the retry for a group of tasks yet, but you can achieve this using callbacks:

```py
a = EmrOperator(..., retries=0)
a_sensor = EmrSensor(, retries=0, on_failure_callback=emr_a_callback)

def emr_a_callback(ti, dag_run,):
    max_retries = 3
    retry_num = ti.xcom_pull(dag_ids=ti.task_id, key="retry_num")
    if retry > max_retries:
        retrun # do nothing
    task_a = dag_run.get_task_instance("<task a id>")
    task_a.state = None # pass a state to None
    ti.state = None # pass the sensor state to None
```